Why does this regex return a 500?
#[Route('/displayer/{slug}', name: 'app_displayer', requirements: ['slug' =>'/[a-z-_]+(?:\.pdf)$/'])]
public function displayer(string $slug): BinaryFileResponse|RedirectResponse


the regex in the requirements route parameter return a 500 when it's working with the preg_match php function
with preg_match :
dd(preg_match('/[a-z-_]+(?:\.pdf)$/', 'balade_en_laisse.pdf'));

The return is true:
DisplayerController.php on line 18:
1

with symfony :
error 500
can't figure out why!

Try '/[a-z_-]+\.pdf$/'

To answer the "why" part, - usually denotes a character range inside [], and a-z-_ is going to be problematic from that perspective. Whenever I have - inside brackets, I put it at the end; it seems that parsers recognize this as not being a range indicator in that position.

Still not working, thanks anyway guys :)

Well...what exactly did you change in your code since the question was marked as a duplicate?

my issue concerns the controller attribute handle by symfony (and the requirements parameters in it ).As i said my regex works fine using directly in the preg_match function.
